# How to get the list item values from the table data in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having one webtable with class name as MessageTable and having the below list item inside the table data(td)

```
<td>
<ul class="error">
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="error in errors">Validation1</li>
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="error in errors">Validation2</li>
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="error in errors">Validation3</li>
</ul>
</td>
```

I need to read all the above content (Validation1,Validation2,Validation3) from web page and need to validate against the expected validation Message.

Comment: Why not create a `List<WebElement>` collection and then spin through it?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I have used the List<WebElement> collection and it is working fine achieve my scenario      WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("messageTable"));
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
             
 for(WebElement element:rows ){
          
  System.out.println(element.getText());
 
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="error in errors"` only appears in your table.
Try this:

```
List<WebElement> elems= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li.ng-binding.ng-scope[ng-repeat$='errors']"));

for(WebElement element:elems ){
    if(element.getText().equals("ur validation message")){
       //do something as ur wish.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  noor. I have used the below steps and it is working fine. for(WebElement element:rows ){ System.out.println(element.getText()); }

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the above question. Please find the working steps

```
 WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("messageTable"));
    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

        for(WebElement element:rows ){

            System.out.println(element.getText());

    }
```